# Array is being returned as empty instead of a list of numbers

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, I'm working on a program for my class to find the leading digit of numbers from a text file and sort them.  I know I don't have the best coding skills out there since I'm a beginner, but I have an idea on how to do it.  Somehow, I've encountered a problem where the array that's suppose to be returned comes out to be empty.  This array is returned twice, actually.  The first time, to the main method, it returns neatly, but when it's returned to `change3()`, it returns "`[].`"

I've tried to change the variables around, and even tried to combine the methods, but nothing works and I just get errors.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class PG 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        List<String> Strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        Strings = change(); // it works perfectly right here
        System.out.println(Strings); // it works perfectly right here
        List<Integer> Integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integers = change2();
        List<Integer> leads = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        leads = change3();
    }


    public static List<String> change()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> list_S = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) 
        {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                line = line.replaceAll(",", "");
                int result = Integer.parseInt(line);
                List<Integer> list_I = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                list_I.add(result);
                list_S.add(line);
        }
        return list_S;
    }

    public static List<Integer> change2()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list_I = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) 
        {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                line = line.replaceAll(",", "");
                int result = Integer.parseInt(line);
                List<String> list_S = new ArrayList<String>();
                list_I.add(result);
                list_S.add(line);
        }
        return list_I;

    }

    public static List<Integer> change3()
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list = change();  // This is supposed to give me a list of numbers(string) so it can help me find the leading digit
        System.out.println(list); // checking to see if the list even has numbers in it.  It does not.  It returns [] as if nothing is in the list.
        List<Integer> leads = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            // get the leading integer
        }
        return leads;
    }
}
```

Basically, for right now, I just want it to print the list in the method `change3()`, so I can continue to work on the program.

Comment: Do you know that debugger would show you the problem in no time?

Comment: *Strings = change(); // it works perfectly right here* hard to agree since there are no Strings declared anywhere. So for now, it is just a compilation error.

Comment: *Array is being returned as empty* maybe you are not adding anything to it? For whatever reasons you ommit that part of the code.

Comment: add input and expected output

Comment: System.out.println(Strings);  That prints out a list of numbers, System.out.println(list) which is basically supposed to be the same thing doesn't.

Comment: please add input and expected output for better solution

Comment: Basically the input is a .txt file with a bunch of numbers separated by commas.  I scan the file and add it to an array.  Basically I'm just using that array to find the leading digit of each number and add the leading digits to another array; however, the array of numbers is being returned empty.

Comment: But System.in is not a file or are you piping it on the command line? I guess then the file is at EOF the second time you call change() and there is nothing more to read.

Comment: Oh my bad.  I'm doing "java PG1.java < numbers.txt" in the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. it should work. if its not working please comment the issue.

Also match this code with your.

There are some changes in change method. I have removed redundant code.

I will suggest to pass the list in all 3 change methods if its same list being used. so you don't have to read it again with the help of scanner.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class PG 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        List<String> Strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        Strings = change(); // it works perfectly right here
        System.out.println(Strings); // it works perfectly right here
        List<Integer> Integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integers = change2();
        List<Integer> leads = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        leads = change3();
    }


    public static List<String> change()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> list_S = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) 
        {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                line = line.replaceAll(",", "");
                list_S.add(line);
        }
        return list_S;
    }

    public static List<Integer> change2()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list_I = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) 
        {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                line = line.replaceAll(",", "");
                int result = Integer.parseInt(line);
                list_I.add(result);
        }
        return list_I;

    }

    public static List<Integer> change3()
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list = change();  // This is supposed to give me a list of numbers(string) so it can help me find the leading digit
        System.out.println(list); // checking to see if the list even has numbers in it.  It does not.  It returns [] as if nothing is in the list.
        List<Integer> leads = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            // get the leading integer
        }
        return leads;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help; however, I'm still getting the same output, an empty array.  I know my code is horrendous, but I would like to understand why the array is returning as empty.

Comment: I ended up fixing it.  I basically just got rid of change3( ) and put it in the main method.

Comment: This answer doesn’t solve the real problem which is that the input file had been read to EOF before change3() was called.